# Exclude a parent element and its children from hide() action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im building this menu but I'm having a problem with excluding a parent and its children. I hope to solve this without extra classes.

So the way it suppose to work is to click a `a.clicked` and it `.hide()` the `li elements` outside its own `li` but with in the scope of the `ul`

its no problem finding the parent `ul` and put a class on the `li` which i do `li.active`. The hard thing here becomes to exclude all the elements inside the `li.active`. 
It do sound messy so i try to comment as best i can in the script.

Thanks guys for input

EDIT: i done a poor job explaining but like i click `level 1 - 1`and `level 1 - 2` is suppose to hide and thats the pattern as we go deeper down the menu with 2 - 1 ect

first of here is the **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Abj9u/6/

```
$('.clicked').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    //activate this li
    $this.parent('li:first').addClass('active');

    //hide the other level (1)(2)(3)(4)(ect..) li items
    //is there a way to exlude .active li and its children without adding a class like .sub to the sub li's?
    $this.parents('ul:first').find('li').not('.active').hide();

    //add class to this for style
    $this.addClass('selected');

    //show the sub ul
    $this.parent().children('ul:first').show();
});​
```

**html**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicked">Level 1 - 1</a>

        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.1 - 1</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.1 - 1</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.2 - 1</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.2 - 1</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.3 - 1</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.3 - 1</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
        </ul>                
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicked">Level 1 - 2</a>

        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.1 - 2</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.1 - 2</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.2 - 2</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.2 - 2</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 2.3 - 2</a>
                <ul class="hidden"><li><a href="#" class="clicked">Level 3.3 - 2</a></li></ul>                
            </li>
        </ul>                
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: If you hide the parent, the children will automatically be hidden too, so all you really need to do is hide the relevant `li`s, right?

Comment: @Gareth: That's what I'm thinking.  Something like `$this.parents('ul:first > li').not('.active').hide();`

Comment: yes thats what I'm trying to do. its basically hide all the other `li's` on the same level so to speak

Comment: @MarkM that does not work, the other `li's` are still visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().hide()
```

as for why this works, it's fairly self explanatory:

- starting from this child element...
- find the first parent LI...
- then find all of this LI's siblings...
- hide them.

Comment: yes that actually works, i thought it was crazy at first :) if you got a minute could you update your answer why this work and short how? thanks

Comment: yes but what does `siblings` mean in this context? every other `li` element in this `ul` (not nested li's)?

Comment: A sibling would be any element at the same level/node on the DOM tree. So, the siblings of an LI would be the other LIs and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the next `ul` up the tree, hiding ALL the `li`s, then showing only the current `li`?

```
$this.parents('ul:first > li').hide();
$this.parent().show();
```

**Edit**: The other answer is a nicer solution though...

Comment: this does not work tho, it still hides all the other `li's` in that scope of the parent. this could work if it would unhide the child `li's` on that show to.

Comment: I've edited to just find direct children of the parent `ul`. But like I said, if the other answer works use that - it's simpler.

Comment: @Dejan.S :-) Working without any easy way of testing will have that result sometimes.